# How can I start command line from SmartGit?

Tags: smartgit

SmartGit seems to be far superior to GitHub for Windows, but I am missing one feature - ability to start git command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SmartGit/Hg 4.5 (and older) do not offer to start the git command line, however you may configure the 'Directory Tool' (Preferences, Tools) to open a terminal (or DOS box), so you can invoke the command line quickly.

**Update:** Since SmartGit/Hg 4.6, you can configure multiple **Directory** tools in the Preferences. After a fresh install (or after removing `tools.xml` from SmartGit/Hg's settings directory), default tools will be created. If your `git` executable is *not* on the path, an **Open Git-Shell** tool will be among them.

Comment: How do I do that? In SmartGit 4.6.5 there is already an entry `Open in Terminal` in the Tools menu, but no `git` is available there.